# What is the purpose of a TEST instruction that has the same register for both operands?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

```
testl   %esi, %esi
jle .L7
```

I mean I understand that `test` actually ANDs the operands, but what is it doing in this case here?

Comment: When you read the documentation for (what processor is this) what does it say about these two instrucitons. In particular with respect to flags?   The answer is right there in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The `jle` in the line after the `testl` says what happens: if `esi` is non-positive (0 or less), jump to `.L7`.